# How to include '\' character in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I'm trying to create a string in javascript which needs to be valid JSON the string is

```
{"query":"FOR u IN Countries RETURN {\"_key\":u._key}"}
```

I keep going around in circles as to how i can include the `\` character given its also used to escape the quote character. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let JSON encoder do the job:

```
> s =  'FOR u IN Countries RETURN {"_key":u._key}'
"FOR u IN Countries RETURN {"_key":u._key}"

> JSON.stringify({query:s})
"{"query":"FOR u IN Countries RETURN {\"_key\":u._key}"}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the backslash itself:

```
{"query":"FOR u IN Countries RETURN {\\\"_key\\\":u._key}"}
```

First pair of backslashes represents `'\'` symbol in the resulting string, and `\"` sequence represents a double quotation mark (`'"'`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\` for double quoted strings

i.e.

```
var s = "{\"query\":\"FOR u IN Countries RETURN {\\\"_key\\\":u._key}\"}";
```

Or use single quotes

```
var s = '{"query":"FOR u IN Countries RETURN {\"_key\":u._key}"}';
```

Comment: It's JavaScript, not PHP/Perl; using single quotation marks won't affect interpolation rules, because, well, there are none. )

Comment: for what i know escaping is done with one backslash not two ( two means you want the charecter "\"  in the string